# Javascript TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Tags: javascript, html, forms, typeerror, getelementbyid

Here is my `html` code:

```
<form name="searchForm" action="javascript:;" method="post" />
  <p>
   <label for="search">Search the site:</label>
   <input type="text" id="search" name="search" value="xhr" />
   <input type="submit" value="Search" />
 </p>
</form>
```

In the header, I included my JavaScript file with the following specific code:

```
window.onload = function () {
    getValues = function (id) {
    var i, values = [], form = document.getElementById(id);
    for (i = 0; i < form.length ;i++) {
        values.push( form.elements[i].value );
    }
    return values;
  }
}
```

I've tried to access the function with `console.log(getValues("searchForm") );` but instead in my `Firefox` console, I received  the following error: `TypeError: form is null`.

Can anyone suggest why this doesn't work?

Comment: Because `searchForm` is a `name`, not an `id`.

Comment: I tryed also to debug with `form = document.getElementById("searchForm");` and after to output with `console.log()` but i recive `null` value of `getElementById()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `name` attribute's value, not `id`. So either you need to change `name` to `id` or use

```
form = document.getElementsByName(id)[0];
```

Also note that if you use the above code, it will return `NodeList` so you need to use index to get the desired element.

Comment: That was my intention first time, now works in both ways!

Comment: i think for now i will use `getElementById`, code is more clean~ yea lets say like this

Answer (score 1):

To get all the values of a form:

```js
"use strict";

var findValuesIn = function(form) {
  
  var fields = form.querySelectorAll('input,textarea,select'),
      values = {},
      i;
  
  for (i in fields) {
    values[ fields[i].name ] = fields[i].value; 
  }
  
  return values;
  
}


document.getElementById('obtainValues').addEventListener('click',function(){

  var ourForm = document.getElementById('f');
  
  var vals = findValuesIn(ourForm);
  
  // debug
  document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(vals);
  
});
```

```css
input, select, textarea {
  float: left;
}
button {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  margin: 1em;
}
label {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 10em;
}
output {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<form name="f" id="f">

  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  
  <label for="search">Search</label>
  <input type="search" name="search" />
  
  <label for="favouriteColour">Favourite Colour</label>
  <select name="favouriteColour">
    <option>red</option>
    <option>blue</option>
    <option>yellow</option>
  </select>
  
  <button id="obtainValues">obtain values</button>
  
</form>

<output id="debug" form="f"></output>
```

Comment: nice, you use the function `querySelectorAll` to collect data.